# Opencv Black Dots Detection

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin

I'm trying to use `Simpleblop` `FeatureDetector`, on photo taken by camera.

That should be find 7 to 107 blops. Sometimes working but usually does not work when changes ambients light or the device shade.

If I change the threshold value its works.

I tried `ThreshOtsu` its not worked on shadow but Binarry 90 - 133 is working generally, maybe my filters is not correct I dont know.

My code:

```
Imgproc.CvtColor(m, m, Imgproc.ColorRgb2gray);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(m, m, new Org.Opencv.Core.Size(5, 5), 30);
Imgproc.MorphologyEx(m, m, Imgproc.MorphClose, Imgproc.GetStructuringElement(Imgproc.MorphRect, new Size(15, 15)));
Imgproc.Threshold(m, m, 122, 255, Imgproc.ThreshBinary);

MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
FeatureDetector blobDetector = FeatureDetector.Create(FeatureDetector.Simpleblob);
blobDetector.Detect(m, matOfKeyPoints);
```

what I am doing:

[image: Result]

What should I do for clear detection ? Like this :

[image]

Comment: It seems clear enough to me. Just remove edge black shadow using some method (flood maybe) and you're fine.

Comment: Yeah its clear but I dont know how clear shadow, I searched much times but everyone tells how, I cannot find code

Comment: @AleksandarToplek If do you know how, please share some code or link

Comment: Didn't use OpenCV, but with a brightness threshold of 0.4 I got it mostly right, and if I then excluded all blobs with less than 2/3rd of the average blob size, all edge noise was removed.